# Using audio_service in SDK34 targered compilations

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio, audio-service

We are using audio_service for a Flutter app for Android. Everything works correctly when compiling for target SDK33. In AndroidManifest.xml file, we have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK"/>
```

as is indicated in the documentation. However, when compiling the application for target SDK34, it stops working. Are we missing something? Where could the issue be? Thank you.

Comment: You can insert a code block into your question to get correct formatting. The more information you can provide, the more likely it is that someone might be able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Hi, @RyanHeise. Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I have updated the post. Could you help us? Are we missing something to target it to SDF34? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any specific error message to your post, so it's not guaranteed to fix your problem, but you now need to declare a foreground service type for android 14.
See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required